# Phone restarts when downloading a file multiple times using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to download a file (size - 4 MB, extenssion - .apk). When download completes, I am giving it to Android's install manager to do it's job. Now my problem is, if I download the file multiple times (4 -5 times), my phone gets restarted.

**UI Flow**

I have a button with "Download" as text, on click of it, I execute the below code:

```
static void downloadApp(Activity context, StorageReference storageRef, String fileName) throws IOException {
    File localFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + fileName);
    localFile.createNewFile();
    storageRef.child(fileName)
            .getFile(localFile)
            .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> installApp(context, localFile))
            .addOnFailureListener(Crashlytics::logException);
}
```

And on success of the download, I am trying to install the app as below:

```
private static void installApp(Activity context, File apkFile) {
    Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    context.startActivity(installIntent);
}
```

When the install manager opens, I click "Cancel" button to go back and click on "Download" button again.

If I repeat the step for 4 times (sometimes 5), my phone reboots.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong. I am guessing it as a defect from Firebase SDK, as I have followed the Documentation guide carefully here. And even though something wrong is there in my code, it should throw any Exception or in worst case an Error (maybe OutOfMemory), but instead it restarts. (A very bad experience for my users)

Comment: Does this happen on the emulator, physical devices, or both? Does it happen on multiple devices? Is there legitimately *nothing* in logcat? This is going to be pretty much impossible if we've got no logs or anything to see what the issue is.

Comment: It happens every time. I haven't checked it in emulator. My device is Moto G3. Android 6.0. Logcat not showing anything wrong. It just prints the Activity logs printed by Firebase Analytics. Let me know if you want to me to try something different way.

Comment: Can you try a different device (or the emulator) and see if it works again. I want to see if this is a device specific issue or if it's across devices/OS versions.